# Tracking time online in MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, time, tracking

I have an website build in MVC4 .NET. Now I want to tracking the time user had online in my website. Example: User open browser and then login to my website and active on my website about 30 minutes then close the browser. I want to store 30 minutes to database but I don;t know how to implement it. Please help me because I very need to do it now. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1314/Tracking-users-login-logout-times-on-your-site) is a script that track user login/logout times on a website. It's a simple script that It has used on some of the sites. Also with this script you can see how many users are online at your site.

But the problem is when the user close the browser he do not log out. his session goes to expire

one of the other ways is [global action filter](http://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/archive/2010/08/15/asp-net-mvc-3-global-action-filters.aspx) that intercepts requests to all actions on all controllers, then you can get the time of each action in the database for the current user and page. To save hitting the database too hard, you could cache these values and invalidate them every few minutes, depending on how much traffic you're dealing with.

**UPDATE**
about Closing the Browser This is not something that's provided for in the normal web http protocol. There's no real way to know for sure when the browser closes; you can only **sort of** know. You have to throw together an ugly hack to get any level of certainty and even then it's bound to fail in plenty of edge cases or cause nasty side effects.

The normal work-around is to send **ajax requests** at intervals from the browser to your server to set up a sort of **heartbeat**. When the heartbeat stops, the browser closed and so you kill the session. But again: this is a horrible hack. In this case, the main problems are that it's easy to get false positives for a failed heartbeat if the server and client to get out of sync or there's a javascript error, and there's a side effect that your session will never expire on it's own.

Comment: Thank you so much for answer. Yes, My problem is same you, I think if user close the browser but not click logout. So how we can know that event and save the time when session goes to expire.